# Hashkiveinu Avinu Vs Hashkiveinu Hashem Elokeinu

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, maariv, bircas-krias-shema

In the bracha of Hashkiveinu, in ma'ariv, Ashkenazim (at least, all Ashkenazi communities and siddurim I've seen) start the bracha with

> השכיבנו **ה' אלוקינו**

Whereas all Sefardi communities and siddurim I've seen use

> השכיבנו **אבינו**

What is the reason for this difference? And where is it brought down?

Comment: Probably there are kabbalistic and poetic reasons. For example one has acrostic היא and one הא, Hei is always good but why would you mention Hee, she, during a time of Din namely evening. Just a speculation and you might check siddur haRashash or something if it's important to you but per Rabbi Nachman the main thing is just the simple meaning of the words.